# Android App With ListView Launching Too Slow

Tags: java, android, listview, android-sqlite

This app I am working on includes a SQLLite Database, a query to PHONE.CONTACTS and nested while loops as shown below. It basically lists all the contacts on the phone in a custom list view. When I test the app, the list view loads around one minute or so. Could you please tell me what's the reason behind that? Is it because I am having the queries on UI Thread instead of a background Thread? or using SQLLite update() method inside a while loop is too expensive? or because of RegEx? If this is not the right way to do it then could you please advise me the right approach? I'd appreciate your answer.

**MainFragment.java:**

```
//SINGLETON
personDataList = PersonDataSingleton.getInstance().getPersonDataList();

//DATABASE
db = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
sqlDbWrite = db.getWritableDatabase();
values = new ContentValues();
ContentValues timeValues = new ContentValues(); 
sqlDbRead = db.getReadableDatabase();

//QUERIES
cursorProjection = new String[]{DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SOCIAL_POINT, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_LOOKUP};
cursorTest = sqlDbRead.query(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, cursorProjection, null, null, null, null, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SOCIAL_POINT + " DESC");

mProjection = new String[]{ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI};
mCursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, mProjection, null, null, null, null);

//COLUMN INDICES
int testStringIndex = cursorTest.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SOCIAL_POINT);
int testContactsNumberIndex = cursorTest.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_LOOKUP);
int contactNameIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
int contactsNumberIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER);
int mThumbNailUriIndex = mCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.PHOTO_THUMBNAIL_URI);

//NESTED WHILE LOOPS
cursorTest.moveToPosition(-1);
while (cursorTest.moveToNext())
{
    testString = cursorTest.getInt(testStringIndex);
    String testContactsNumber = cursorTest.getString(testContactsNumberIndex);

    if (subtractPoint > 1)
    {
    testString = testString - daysSince;
    timeValues.put(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_SOCIAL_POINT, testString);
    sqlDbWrite.update(DatabaseHelper.DATABASE_TABLE, timeValues, DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_LOOKUP + "=?", new String[]{testContactsNumber});
    }

    mCursor.moveToPosition(-1);
    while (mCursor.moveToNext())
    {
    contactName = mCursor.getString(contactNameIndex);
    contactsNumber = mCursor.getString(contactsNumberIndex);               
    mThumbNailUri = mCursor.getString(mThumbNailUriIndex);
    revisedContactsNumber = contactsNumber.replaceAll("\\D+", "");

        if (revisedContactsNumber.equals(testContactsNumber))
        {
        personDataList.add(new PersonData(contactName, contactsNumber, mThumbNailUri, testString, "01"));
        }
    }
}

//ARRAY ADAPTER
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
mCustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter1(getActivity(), personDataList);
setListAdapter(mCustomAdapter);
}
```

Comment: try adding `sqlDbWrite.beginTransaction();` just before loops, with `sqlDbWrite.setTransactionSuccessful();` and `sqlDbWrite.endTransaction();` upon loop completion. You might also want to have a look at [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) fro more info regarding transactions.

Comment: what actually do you want to achieve?

Comment: @pskink I am fetching contact names and numbers from phone database and have my own custom database with points, phone number columns.And I am using nested while loops for matching phone numbers between Custom Database and Phone Contact database and populate the list accorrding to that. There is also a CallLog DB query to check recent calls but I didn't put the CallLog - Own Database matching while loop code here not to complicate the question as I am almost sure the slowness was because if this nested while loops.I use RegEx because number format of CallLog and Contacs database are different.

Comment: and what is that `Custom Database` used for? why not to use the standard db?

Comment: When I say custom database I mean a sqllite databasehelper class. Sorry if it's not the right term. I am using this custom database to store points for each contacts. I take call details from CallLog Database and match the calls by number with this Custom Database with a while loop and if a number has been called then some points are added to the related record in the Custom Database. I also match this Custom Database with Phone Contact database by phone numbers with nested while loops to populate the list view. Could you advise a better approach for this?

Comment: see https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/contacts-provider.html ^F `Custom data rows`

Comment: Does this basically mean I can store my custom data (points e.g.) in standard Phone Contact database and don't need an extra database at all to store custom data?

Comment: yes, this is for storing a custom contact's data

Comment: I am definitely having a look on that one. Thank you for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. off load the database operation to a background thread, use implement a CursorLoader with the LoaderManager to accomplish this.
2. Handle updating the listAdapter in the OnLoadFinished() callback of the LoaderManager implementation.

Documentation on Loaders and the use of LoaderManager
[Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html)

and here is the android walkthrough that uses a CursorLoader to retrieve data from the contacts provider.
[Retrieving a List of Contacts](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/retrieve-names.html)

Answer (score 1):

1. You should get the contacts in background thread.
2. Use RecyclerView for (probably) such a long lists.